# Using the (antiquated) C crypt() method for homework - the compiler won't link?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, clion, crypt

all:

I'm supposed to use the crypt( ) function in a homework assignment. It's an old C method, which is probably pretty insecure, but it's just for demonstrative purposes.

The only thing, I can't figure out how to use the dang function. I'm using CLion as my IDE on Ubuntu. It's supposed to be defined in the <crypt.h> or <unistd.h>, but I cannot get this thing to compile. The crypt( ) function has an "undefined reference" error after building the project. I know it's one of those two libraries, though - so what's up? Is there an issue with linking to that library or something? I've read around and come across "use -lcrypt", but I'm not entirely sure what to do with that inside CLion. The only explanations were involving make files; which, didn't apply to me (or they did, and I didn't know how it related). There's not much documentation for it, either, because of how outdated the function is.

Thanks, all.

EDIT:
Thanks, Eugene! I think I figured this one out. . .

`target_link_libraries(CryptExample -lcrypt)`

In the CMake file.

Comment: So your real question is "how to link with specific libraries in CLion?". And this is what you need to search for

Comment: Hey, Eugene. I think so; I've been doing some searching online about that very topic. Problem is, I don't know the exact name of the "crypt" library and how to use it in the context of CLion. So far, I've found: target_link_libraries( x ... ), but what the heck do I call the library itself? Thanks, Eugene.

Comment: Instead of updating your question with the answer you should post it as an answer to your question.

Comment: Sorry, Jerry. New to this board. I'll do that instead.

Comment: On some newer builds of system it might be -lxcrypt and different function - crypt_r , because libcrypt was scheduled in 2018  for removal of all unsafe functions (they were not thread safe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone that stumbles upon this in the future, add

```
target_link_libraries(CryptExample -lcrypt)
```

to your CMakeLists.txt in the CLion IDE. It should be put under the add_executable(. . .) line. Replace "CryptExample" with whatever you named your project.